# .load does not reload div as expected

Tags: jquery

I had a div that loads a file generated by a .sh script. In my code I have a function that needs to reload that div so it loads the latest data from the file generated by the .sh

The div (page2.php)

```
<div class="connection_details" id="connection_details_id" style="display:none;">
<p> <?php include('2.log'); ?> </p>
</div>
```

The function (in php)

```
function ShowOutput() {
        echo '<script>$("#connection_details_id").load(location.href+" #connection_details_id>*","");</script>';
        echo '<script>document.getElementById("connection_details_id").style.display = "block";</script>';
    }
```

The above does not work. However I have the EXACT same code on a previous page, and there it does work. I absolutely cannot understand why the above doesn't work.

If I use `echo '<script>$( "#connection_details_id" ).load( "2.log" );</script>';` it works but that triggers a small refresh. The code in the function does which looks prettier.

I can do (in php)

```
function ShowOutput() {
    echo '<script>$( "#connection_details_id" ).load( "2.log" );</script>';
    echo '<script>$("#connection_details_id").load(location.href+" #connection_details_id>*","");</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("connection_details_id").style.display = "block";</script>';
}
```

Which works (file is reloaded and no refresh is visible to the user) but that seems like doing to same thing twice to me. Since it works fine with `echo '<script>$("#connection_details_id").load(location.href+" #connection_details_id>*","");</script>';` on my first page I don't understand why its not working on my second page.

Comment: What url do you expect `location.href+" #connection_details_id>*"` to be?

Comment: That of the current page (page2.php).